# Stopping a node

Tags: nodeos, node

So I have setup a ubuntu 18.04 server to develop on but I am stuck as it only has 4g ram and needs 8 to run. What I need to know is how to stop the node so that I can shut down the server to add more ram. Thank you.

```
joe@tmiot:~/contracts/eosio.cdt$ ./build.sh
=========== Building eosio.cdt ===========


OS name: 
OS Version: 18.04
CPU speed: 1932.446Mhz
CPU cores: 4
Physical Memory: 3856 Mgb
Disk install: /dev/sda2
Disk space total: 915G
Disk space available: 861G
Your system must have 7 or more Gigabytes of physical memory installed.
Exiting now.
./build.sh: line 97: : command not found
joe@tmiot:~/contracts/eosio.cdt$
```

Comment: sure that nodeos has been built and started with only 4GB of Ram?

Comment: My server which is a desk top I got from a night club that was fire boomed, has an intel i5 1tb hd and 2x2g ram chips, so I need to replace them.

Answer (score 1):

Find your nodeos process ID and kill it!

You can kill the nodeos process using:

```
pkill nodeos
```

or using the PID which can be listed by

```
ps -aux | grep nodeos
```

and then killing the process using

```
kill PIDofNodeos
```

Comment: Thanks Kabir, do you know what commands to use? I am very new to ubuntu.

Comment: "ps -aux" will list all running processes, "kill [PID_of_traget_process]" kills the process. 
--> You need to find the PID in the list displayed with "ps -aux" and replace [PID_of_traget_process] with it to kill the process.

Comment: "ps aux | grep nodeos" will filter the list of processes to the ones that have "nodeos" in their name, you should get just 2, the actual server process and this command reporting itself which you can ignore. Then kill the process by the PID number

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just execute `pkill nodeos`.